# How to initial array of object like UILabel in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I would like to initial a array of object like UILabel with repeating parameters like this

```
var labels = [UILabel](repeating : UILabel(), count : 7)
```

But I find all items in the array point to the same label instance. Is that expected? How can I create the array with different instances inside? Thanks.

Comment: For what do u want to have array of UILabels? Why cant u have [String]?

Comment: This init method is not appropriate for reference types.

Answer (score 2):

For example you could use a cycle to create labels:

```
var labels = [UILabel]()
for _ in 0 ..< 7 {
    let label = UILabel()
    labels.append(label)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant, but

```
var labels = (1...7).map { _ in UILabel() }
```

will do the trick.

Apparently, `Array.init(repeating:count:)` evaluates the repeating element only once, and then repeats it, which makes some sense, I guess… So you need a solution that will iterate and call `UILabel()` on each step. A `for` loop and a number of other different techniques should also work.